# Parse XHTML page with jQuery, remove element and append to div

Tags: jquery, parsing, xhtml

I get a url of an XHTML page (stored on my computer) thanks to jQuery and I want to parse this page and then remove items of my XML.

My XHTML page

```
<html>
 ...
    <exampleXML>
        <dataset>a</dataset>
        <dataset>b</dataset>
        <dataset>c</dataset>
    </exampleXML>
...
</html>
```

My jQuery code

```
var url_val = $("#xhtml_page").val();
$.get(url_val, function(data) {
    $(data).find("dataset").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "a"){
           $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    $("#body-tmpl").html('<div id="id_container"></div>');
    $("#id_container").html($(data));
});
```

And When my items are removed I would send the contents of my new XHTML in a div.

But unfortunately, I can not removed the XHTML elements (exemple a) and put the new page in a div. It is the best solution?

Before attempting to remove items, I put my XHTML in an iframe.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="XHTMLfile.html">
#document<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> … </head>
    <body style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; font: 11px sans-serif; cursor: auto;">
    <img id="hiddenImage" style="display:none" src="http://soft.sourceforge.net        /img/hidden.png"></img>
    <img id="loadingImage" style="display:none" src="http://soft.sourceforge.net             /img/loading.gif"></img>
    <img id="logo" style="display:none" src="http://soft.sourceforge.net/img/logo.png"> </img>
    <noscript> … </noscript>
    <div style="display:none"> … </div><div style="position: absolute; top: 1%; right: 2%;      text-align: right;"> … </div>
    <input type="button" value="x" style="position: fixed; visibility: visible; right: 10.5px; top: 492.333px;"></input>
    <canvas width="1000" height="700"></canvas>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px;"> … </div>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Now I have it when I put it in a div :

```
    <div id="id_container" style="width:1000px; height:700px;">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </meta><link href="http://soft.sourceforge.net/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
    </link><img id="hiddenImage" style="display:none" src="http://soft.sourceforge.net/img/hidden.png"></img>
    <img id="loadingImage" style="display:none" src="http://soft.sourceforge.net/img/loading.gif"></img>
    <img id="logo" style="display:none" src="http://soft.sourceforge.net/img/logo.png"></img>
    <noscript> … </noscript>
   <div style="display:none">
    … </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you don't change the value of `data`. You always parse the string (the response) `data` again and again by using `$(data)`. You should assign `$(data)` once to a variable and manipulate it. Like this

```
$.get(url_val, function(data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    $data.find("dataset").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "a") {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    $("#body-tmpl").html('<div id="id_container"></div>');
    $("#id_container").html($data);
```

});

Comment: Thanks but I have a problem because my new XHTML is in the div but the content did not show. I think it is because I do not have the tags `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`. It have been removed.

Comment: Could you please give an example how your current result looks like and how your desired result should look like?